# incompatible return value type

Tags: java, unit-testing, profiler, easymock

I am new to unit testing, Recently I used profiler to populate different metrics depending on different conditions using if-else statements. I have written a unit test to check if the right metrics is getting populated. However I m getting a `Incompatible return value type` error. The code snippet is as follows:

```
ProfilerObject1 mockObject = ctrl.createMock(ProfilerObject1.class);
EasyMock.expect(ProfilerObject2.func1()).andReturn(mockObject);
PopulateMetric(m1);
EasyMock.expectLastCall().once();
control.replay();
```

I m getting the incompatible return value error on line 2(EasyMock.expect call), whereas the function returns the object of type ProfilerObject1. I have no clue on why I m getting this error.

Any help would really be appreciated. TIA

PS: I m using this snippet at 2 separate places and at the 2nd place it gives `no last call on mock available` error. Which confuses me even more.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the expectation on a static method call. It is not supported by EasyMock. To mock static methods you should use PowerMock along with EasyMock. Check below sample on how to do.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ ProfilerObject2.class })
public class TestClass {

   @Test
   public void test() {

       PowerMock.mockStatic(ProfilerObject2.class);
       ProfilerObject1 mockObject = ctrl.createMock(ProfilerObject1.class);
       EasyMock.expect(ProfilerObject2.func1()).andReturn(mockObject);
       // your rest of the code goes here
       PowerMock.replayAll();

   }

}
```